# JVM heap stack get full after a duration

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, hikaricp

I have a spring based consumer major task to I/O of events in relational based database. Having Jpa with Hibernate as ORM. 
My consumer works fine with data around 10K records but got failed out when we search event in data around 2 million records. When doing Root Cause Analysis (RAC) using logs. I got error like:

```
> >  Application exception overridden by rollback exception java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space 2019-03-27 16:50:48,942
> INFO  i.s.s.e.s.EventServiceImpl -Some Exception Occurred in
> fetchAllEventsByReferenceId :
> org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not
> roll back JPA transaction; nested exception is
> javax.persistence.PersistenceException: unexpected error when
> rollbacking
>         at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doRollback(JpaTransactionManager.java:548)
>         at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processRollback(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:853)
>         at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.rollback(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:830)
>         at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.completeTransactionAfterThrowing(TransactionAspectSupport.java:522)
>         at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:286)
>         at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
>         at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
>         at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
>         at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
>         at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:133)
```

For time being i tried to clean the heap using -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
.It started well, but now my Hikari pool get busy and got stuck responding and giving exception:

> Error performing load command : org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not extract ResultSet
>
> java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Communications link failure during rollback(). Transaction resolution unknown.
>
> org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not extract ResultSet

Comment: You should create a heapdump when you get an OutOfMemoryError. Then analyze that dump using a tool like Eclipse MAT to see what actually uses that memory.

Comment: Since your method is called `fetchAllEventsByReferenceId` are you trying to load 20k records into memory? Post `fetchAllEventsByReferenceId` method declaration.

Comment: @KarolDowbecki 
this is the method signature
public Map<String, Object> fetchAllEventsByReferenceId(String referenceId, Pageable pageObject, String searchText) 

and I am using spring data jpa ,as per my knowledge we have a first level cache by default with hibernate that is Session object,
so when we call this method might be all 20K record being loaded till that session live, But I don't know how this will work with pageable object in spring.